# ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.TenantMgtAdminServiceClient} - Sending POST request to URL

Tags: linux, docker, wso2, docker-swarm, wso2-identity-server

```
[2020-04-01 01:27:24,091]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler} -  Illegal access attempt at [2020-04-01 01:27:24,0091] from IP address
127.0.0.1 while trying to authenticate access to service TenantMgtAdminService [2020-04-01 01:27:24,092] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.TenantMgtAdminServiceClient}
-  Sending POST request to URL : https://wso2-hml.local.domain:4443/services/TenantMgtAdminService/retrieveTenantsfailed. java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://wso2-hml.local.domain:4443/services/TenantMgtAdminService/retrieveTenants
```

The admin login ok.
The admin of tenant no login.

I changed all properties to the new hostname.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are you trying to invoke the /TenantMgtAdminService/retrieveTenants SOAP service?

Comment: When trying to login using a Tenant, it displays the 401 message for that URL (viewing it in the log).
I tried to access this URL it asks for username and password but I can access it by calling this URL with the admin.

Comment: can you add all the steps you followed when you faced this issue? With the provided info, it's hard to understand what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to authenticate the `TenantMgtAdminService` as `admin@carbon.super` (default super admin of the server) and it is a success.
But if you try to access the same service as an admin of another tenant (`admin@abc.com`), it gives you an HTTP 401 unauthorized.

It is the expected behavior, as the super admin of the server should be able to manage other tenants. But each tenant is totally separated, and unaware of the existence of the other tenants. Even from the Management Console, you **can't** list all the tenants by login as a tenant's admin. Whereas you can list the tenants as super admin user.

[Permission required for retrieveTenants operation](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-multitenancy/blob/master/components/tenant-mgt/org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt/src/main/resources/META-INF/services.xml#L40)

But you can get your tenant information only as the tenant admin using `getTenant` operation.

[Permission required for getTenant operation](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-multitenancy/blob/master/components/tenant-mgt/org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt/src/main/resources/META-INF/services.xml#L56)